# How to Prevent error Mysql ST_PolygonFromText because first and last Coordinate not equals

Tags: mysql, geolocation, gps, geospatial, polygon

I have Query :

`SELECT ST_PolygonFromText(CONCAT('Polygon((',DATA_GPS,'))'))
FROM TABLE_A
CROS JOIN TABLE_B`

Show error :

`Data truncation: Invalid GIS data provided to function st_geometryfromtext.`

Error at line 8 because first and last gps not equal or not close polygon.
show like this :

`Polygon((107.15778031165127 -6.304745648974358 107.15945401007279 -6.304639009497479 107.15949692542361 -6.307624906559413))`

How to query to exclude not close polygon like that ?

Thanks anyway

Comment: Please show an example of  `SELECT ST_AsText(DATA_GPS) FROM TABLE_A CROSS JOIN TABLE_B;` (failing data as well as _good_ data (if any)).

Answer (score 0):

I think the "prevention" needs to happen *before* handing `DATA_GPS` to the Spatial functions.  However, this might work afterwards:

Build a `MultiLineString`, then check with `IsClosed()`.  If necessary, add the original point at the end.

Comment: can you give an example Query ?
Thanks anyway

Comment: @PamungkasJayuda - Show me how you got `DATA_GPS`, tell me what client language you are using, and I may be able to close your polygons for you.

Comment: Hello @RickJames , i want check that close polygon just in MySQL Query. Because i want return from query is already to use. No need validation from client language. Cant we? Regads